# Conspiracy or miraculous coincidence in The usual suspects

Tags: the-usual-suspects

Many of them who repeat watched **The usual suspects** would have noted the shot where two birds fly across the Twin towers. For those who didn't, the link from YouTube is below.

I just couldn't get over this and how to name this. Was wondering is there any similar coincidence like this happened in any other movies. I have seen **The Simpsons** predictions and sci-fi tech gadget ideas in some old movies , but nothing like this. Very creepy.

Comment: Didn't watch the video, nor am I tempted to. Are you looking for another cityscape with birds flying past [note that happens a lot in real-life too], or ... what??

Comment: I did not find this YT video and went back to check in the movie. It was the other way round. Found it interesting and weird.

Comment: It's almost definitely not a conspiracy or a miraculous coincidence.  It seems more like a regular coincidence.

Comment: Welcome to the site DeeJay, but you could not have asked a less appealing question IMO lol - as I have been told by other members repeatedly 'the Stack likes objectivity' and as such I do not believe that any notions in or around 'conspiracy' theory are likely to be entertained in any fashion.

Comment: This point must be added in the 'Terms and Conditions' I suppose Stephen.

Comment: What part of this very ordinary occurrence hints in any way, shape of form towards "conspiracy"?

Comment: "conspiracy" as it is told in the YT video and its not my opinion. I saw it as a weird coincidence only.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing "told" in the video, nothing at all. There isn't even any intelligible soundtrack, no commentary at all, just someone videoing their TV screen [which is in itself risible]. Zero "conspiracy"; lots of Apophenia.

Answer (score 4):

All I can think is that you are suffering from some form of **[Apophenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophenia)**

> **Apophenia** is the tendency to mistakenly perceive connections and meaning between unrelated things. The term was coined by psychiatrist Klaus Conrad in his 1958 publication on the beginning stages of schizophrenia. He defined it as "unmotivated seeing of connections [accompanied by] a specific feeling of abnormal meaningfulness". He described the early stages of delusional thought as self-referential, over-interpretations of actual sensory perceptions, as opposed to hallucinations.

This is a similar mechanism to pareidolia, which led me to once find 'jesus' in my coffee cup.

Neither photo nor cup were intentionally altered in any way.

[image]

Comment: Finally we have something in common.

Comment: Not if you actually think there is a picture of a face in the bottom of my cup; as opposed to some staining caused by not thoroughly washing the dregs of the previous milky coffee from it first, then scratching that stain randomly by stirring.